# Java - How to update JList once Jframe has been loaded

Tags: java, vector, refresh, jframe, jlist

```
        Connection connection = newConnection.createConnection();
        Statement newStat = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet res = newStat.executeQuery("SELECT contactName FROM Contact WHERE accountName='"+m+"'");
        Vector<String> temp = new Vector<String>();
        //res.first();
        while (res.next()){
            temp.add(res.getString("contactName"));
        }
        newStat.close();
        connection.close();
        customerContactList = new JList(temp);
        repaint();
```

---

I have a Jlist with account names, when an account is selected, on the side there is a button which has to be pressed for in order to call the code above. 
The code is supposed to get contact names associated to that account and populate them into 
the JList. This does not happen. The Jlist stays blank, i debugged and the vector temp does get 3 values and stores them into the new jlist, the problem is, JList does not refresh.

How can I make it refresh?

Thanks a lot and I appreciate any help. 
Kunal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new JList you created hasn't been added to any container, so you'd have to add it to the frame, just as the original one was, and then call "validate()" on the frame (always necessary when you add/remove components to a visible window.) But it would be better to call setListData() on the existing JList -- it would update right away, with less flashing around.

Comment: it works! i was creating new jLists for other parts when components where being initialized, this way seems more effective. 

Thanks for your help. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListModel to manipulate the data inside the `JList`. And definitely not create new `JLists` at any step.

You have your `JList` bounded to your `JFrame`. Now you can get the data inside it using

```
    JList list = new JList();
    ListModel model = list.getModel();
```

and modify that model, then send the new model back:

```
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    while (res.next()) {
        listModel.addElement( res.getString("contactName") );
    }
    list.setModel(listModel);
```